# wix site not creating in IIS7

Tags: wix, wix3.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
  <Product Id="e6c96829-cb0e-443c-843d-50f9c497f0b6" Name="Sample"
       Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me"
       UpgradeCode="b3b0a43f-5a27-4974-b9d4-87364345aec0">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="WixSample.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<iis:WebSite Id='DefaultWebSite' Description='Default Web Site'>
  <iis:WebAddress Id='AllUnassigned' Port='80' />
</iis:WebSite>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Sample">
    <Directory Id="MyWebSiteDir" Name="MyWebSite" />        
  </Directory>
</Directory>
<Feature Id="SampleFeature" Title="Sample" Level="1">
</Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

This is the code which I run. Its not showing any error. But when I run MSI the site is not created in the IIS. IIS version is 7. And the WIX version is 3.6.
Even I tried the code in http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/01/25/install-a-new-virtual-directory-to-default-web-site-with-wix.aspx still not working

Comment: the site will be created if you place its definition `<iis:WebSite>` inside the `<Component>` element. If you place it the way you do in your sample, it is used as a locator and as long as you don't do anything else in your code towards IIS, no action is applied to IIS metabase. WiX.chm contains more samples

Comment: Basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561544/wix-unexpected-child-element-website/13566095#13566095

Comment: Even in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561544/wix-unexpected-child-element-website/13566095#13566095 I am getting error:
""The iis:Website/@Directory attribute must be specified when the element has a Component as an ancestor"" .. . . This is the error I am getting

Comment: Edit in your new code, the answer that ChrisPatrick has linked works